# How do I transfer the text messages (sms) from my iPhone to my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, backup, sms

Ideally I could download them in some structured form, but I just want to read my SMS messages on my Mac. Is this possible? (I tried Syphone and it didn't recognize my iPhone 3G)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) before. It's $20 but you can do a lot more with it than just transfer SMS. I'm also assuming you don't want to jailbreak your phone.

Comment: > I'm also assuming you don't want to jailbreak your phone.

Definitely correct

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a convient way using the stock firmware or the iPhone UI. I bellieve SMS are stored in a SQLite DB on the device, if you can gain access to the DB file as you could using jailbroken firmware, then you could export SMS using any app that can read a SQLite database